# Conversion from/to roman numbers

Tags: python, unit-testing, converting

I wrote as an exercise in Test-Driven Development a piece of Python code that contains two functions:

- `roman2dec(roman)`, that converts a roman number (string) into a decimal number (int)
- `dec2roman(dec)`, that converts a decimal number (int) into a roman number (string)

I'd like to read your comments on this code, if there are bad practices, if you would sign it for shipping or if you'd change anything.

```
import re
import math

# Regular expression used to validate and parse Roman numbers
roman_re = re.compile("""^
   ([M]{0,9})   # thousands
   ([DCM]*)     # hundreds
   ([XLC]*)     # tens
   ([IVX]*)     # units
   $""", re.VERBOSE)

# This array contains valid groups of digits and encodes their values.
# The first row is for units, the second for tens and the third for
# hundreds. For example, the sixth element of the tens row yields the
# value 50, as the first is 0.
d2r_table = [
    ['', 'I', 'II', 'III', 'IV', 'V', 'VI', 'VII', 'VIII', 'IX'],
    ['', 'X', 'XX', 'XXX', 'XL', 'L', 'LX', 'LXX', 'LXXX', 'XC'],
    ['', 'C', 'CC', 'CCC', 'CD', 'D', 'DC', 'DCC', 'DCCC', 'CM']]


def roman2dec(roman):
    """Converts a roman number, encoded in a string, to a decimal number."""
    roman = roman.upper()
    match = roman_re.match(roman)

    if not match:
        raise ValueError

    thousands, hundreds, tens, units = match.groups()
    result = 1000 * len(thousands)
    result += d2r_table[2].index(hundreds) * 100
    result += d2r_table[1].index(tens) * 10
    result += d2r_table[0].index(units)

    return result


def dec2roman(dec):
"""Converts a positive decimal integer to a roman number."""
    if dec == 0:
        return ''

    digit = 0
    rem = dec
    result = ''

    # Length in digits of the number dec
    dec_len = int(math.ceil(math.log10(dec)) + 1)

    # Scan the number digit-by-digit, starting from the MSD (most-significant
    # digit)
    while dec_len > 0:
        # Let's take the current digit
        factor = 10 ** (dec_len - 1)
        digit = rem / factor

        # And remove it from the number
        rem = rem - digit * factor

        if dec_len >= 4:
            # Thousands
            result = result + digit * 'M'
        else:
            # Look in the look-up table
            result = result + d2r_table[dec_len - 1][digit]

        dec_len -= 1

    return result
```

**EDIT**: Here is the test suite for dec2roman:

```
class DecToRoman(unittest.TestCase):
    def testZeroIsEmpty(self):
        self.checkString(0, "")

    def testSingleDigits(self):
        self.checkString(1, "I")
        self.checkString(10, "X")
        self.checkString(50, "L")
        self.checkString(100, "C")
        self.checkString(500, "D")
        self.checkString(1000, "M")

    def testSimpleRepeats(self):
        self.checkString(1, "I")
        self.checkString(2, "II")
        self.checkString(3, "III")
        self.checkString(10, "X")
        self.checkString(20, "XX")
        self.checkString(30, "XXX")

    def testSubtraction(self):
        self.checkString(4, "IV")
        self.checkString(9, "IX")
        self.checkString(40, "XL")
        self.checkString(90, "XC")

    def testOther(self):
        self.checkString(89, "LXXXIX")
        self.checkString(145, "CXLV")
        self.checkString(691, "DCXCI")
        self.checkString(1983, "MCMLXXXIII")
        self.checkString(2412, "MMCDXII")
        self.checkString(3309, "MMMCCCIX")

    def checkString(self, decimal, expected_string):
        self.assertEqual(expected_string, new_dec2roman(decimal))
```

Comment: Make this into an extension module? http://www.ioccc.org/1987/wall.c (izajoke)

Comment: It would be easier to just type `import roman` ;) but it's just an exercise!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First of all you should document the fact that your code does not work with numbers above 9999.

Then I think your code will become a bit simpler, if you add a fourth row to your `d2r_table` for the thousands. To avoid repetition you can use a list comprehension:

```
d2r_table = [
    ['', 'I', 'II', 'III', 'IV', 'V', 'VI', 'VII', 'VIII', 'IX'],
    ['', 'X', 'XX', 'XXX', 'XL', 'L', 'LX', 'LXX', 'LXXX', 'XC'],
    ['', 'C', 'CC', 'CCC', 'CD', 'D', 'DC', 'DCC', 'DCCC', 'CM'],
    ['M' * i for i in xrange(0,10) ]]
```

This allows you to not treat the thousands as a special case. So instead of:

```
thousands, hundreds, tens, units = match.groups()
result = 1000 * len(thousands)
result += d2r_table[2].index(hundreds) * 100
result += d2r_table[1].index(tens) * 10
result += d2r_table[0].index(units)
```

you can write:

```
thousands, hundreds, tens, units = match.groups()
result =  d2r_table[3].index(thousands) * 1000
result += d2r_table[2].index(hundreds) * 100
result += d2r_table[1].index(tens) * 10
result += d2r_table[0].index(units)
return result
```

Now you can easily notice the common pattern here: For each number from 0 to 3 you're taking the `i`th row of `d2r_table`, calling `index` on it with the `3-i`th element of `groups` as the argument, then multiplying it with `10**i` and lastly summing the results. You can abstract the common pattern like this if you want:

```
def value_for_group(i):
    group = match.groups[3-i]
    return d2r_table[i].index(group) * 10**i

return sum(value_for_group(i) for i in xrange(0,4))
```

You can also replace the magic numbers 3 and 4, with something more meaningful:

```
num_rows = len(d2r_table)

def value_for_group(i):
    group = match.groups[num_rows - 1 - i]
    return d2r_table[i].index(group) * 10**i

return sum(value_for_group(i) for i in xrange(0, num_rows))
```

This way your code will work without modification if you ever change `d2r_table` to account for extended roman numerals.

---

In your `dec2roman` function you're using integer arithmetic to iterate over the digits of the number. I think it'd be easier and clearer to just convert the number to a string and iterate over the digits with a for loop. By reversing the `d2r_table`, you can use `zip` to iterate over the table and the digits in parallel without any index based loops. This way your `dec2roman` function would look like this:

```
result = ''
# Make digits four digits long so it has the same number of digits
# as d2r_table has rows, then convert each digit to an int
digits = [int(digit) for digit in "%04d" % dec]

for digit, d2r_row in zip(digits, reversed(d2r_table)):
    result += d2r_row[ digit ]

return result
```

You can also use `join` with a generator expression instead of updating `result` imperatively:

```
digits = [int(digit) for digit in "%04d" % dec]
table = reversed(d2r_table)
return ''.join( d2r_row[ digit ] for digit, d2r_row in zip(digits, table) )
```

Again you might also want to replace the 4 in `%04d` with `len(d2r_table)`, so your code will automatically adapt to a longer `d2r_table`.